# ignoring empty lines when comparing two files

Tags: python

I have this comparison function that takes in two files and compares their content line by line. Problem is, it doesn't ignore the blank lines. So if I have the following as File1

```
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)        rxbytes    txbytes
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.6.50860      72.21.91.29.http       CLOSE_WAIT         892        691
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.6.50858      www.v.dropbox.co.https ESTABLISHED      27671       7563
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.6.50857      162.125.17.1.https     ESTABLISHED      17581       3642
```

and compare this with the following as File2

```
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)        rxbytes    txbytes
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.6.50860      72.21.91.29.http       CLOSE_WAIT         892        691




tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.6.50858      www.v.dropbox.co.https ESTABLISHED      27671       7563
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.6.50857      162.125.17.1.https     ESTABLISHED      17581       3642
```

It will take the blank lines into account and compare those empty line with the content in file1.  I've tried using `strip()`, but  it deletes all the spaces in between each char, which I dont want. Is there a way to just delete the empty lines after each line?  I've highlighted the relevant part of my code.

```
def compare(baseline, newestFile):



    baselineHolder = open(baseline)
    newestFileHolder = open(newestFile)

    lines1 = baselineHolder.readlines()
    a = returnName(baseline)
    b = returnName(newestFile)

    for i,lines2 in enumerate(newestFileHolder):
            if not (isEmpty(baseline)) and not (isEmpty(newestFile)):
                if lines2 != lines1[i]:
                    add1 = i + 1
                    print ("line ", add1, " in newestFile is different \n")
```

Comment: [**`str.strip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) won't delete all the spaces in between, only at the front and back of a string.

Comment: Are you aware of the builtin [**`difflib`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#module-difflib)?

Answer (score 0):

do something like:

```
def non_empty_readline(f):
    line = ""
    while not line:
       line = f.readline().strip()
    return line
```

then call both of those from your code (you need a way to advance to the next line on an empty line without affecting your overall loop structure).

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
for i,lines2 in enumerate(newestFileHolder):
```

with

```
for i,lines2 in enumerate(filter(lambda x: len(x) >0 , map(lambda x: x.strip(),newestFileHolder))):
```

map edits the whitespace and filter removes the lines that are then empty

Agree with @PeterWood 's comment that difflib is a better way to go